# Creating Change Sets with Metadata API

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, apexrest, change-set

Is it possible to create, upload, and deploy a Change Set in Apex? For example I can use `/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/ApexClass` to create classes. Is there a similar service for Change Sets? I don't see anything related to deployments on the [SF Metadata API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm).

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't create/alter/delete change sets using the API. There's [some](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DldOAAS) various [ideas](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000aqkDAAQ) you can vote on. In the meantime, you could consider [creating a package](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_packages.htm&language=en_US), which at least helps you group items together, and *can* be used with the Metadata API.

Comment: There is something coming at Dreamforce 2016 called [Artifacts](https://success.salesforce.com/Sessions?eventId=a1Q3000000qQOd9#/session/a2q3A000000sWWJQA2) - "the next-get packaging solution". I don't know yet how this relates to change sets, but it is worth keeping an eye on.